Populate SurveyJS file upload with remote data
I'm using SurveyJS to create a multi step form for users to check their existing profile. The survey is pre-populated with values from an API, so the user can check those and submit changes. Therefore, I also want to populate file upload fields, but can't find a way to do that with remote files.
I'm aware, I can load default values with base64 encoded images, like so:
import { Model } from 'survey-core'
import { Survey } from 'survey-react-ui'
import './App.css'

const surveyJson = {
    elements: [{
        name: "file1",
        title: "Upload a file",
        allowMultiple: true,
        type: "file"
    }]
};

const App = () => {
    const survey = new Model(surveyJson);

    survey.mergeData({
        file1: [
            {
                name: 'file1.svg',
                type: 'image/svg+xml',
                content: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,.....'
            }
        ]
    })

    return (
        <div style={{ minWidth: '500px', minHeight: '400px' }}>
            <Survey model={survey} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App


But this only works once the survey is created and mounted. Since my survey consists of multiple pages and images in them, I would need to download every image and convert it to base64, before loading the survey, like:
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.example.com/person')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const person = data.person;

            person.files = person.files.map((file: any) => {
                // fetch file and convert to base64
                const base64 = "....";

                return {
                    name: file.name,
                    type: file.type,
                    content: base64
                }
            });

            survey.mergeData(person);
        });
}, []);

This seems quite ineffective to me. Maybe there is a more elegant solution to achieve this?

Appreciate you taking the time to nicely describe your question.
You're correct that the current approach is suboptimal. Preloading all images before initializing SurveyJS can indeed cause unnecessary delays and UI thread blocking, especially in a multi-step form scenario and multiple images you need to process for the model.
A more efficient approach would be to defer image loading until after the survey is initialized and to lazy load images as they are needed (about to become visible). This is particularly useful for multi-step forms, where users might take some time to navigate to the next step and your cases is a great fit for this approach.
Fortunately, SurveyJS supports lazy rendering based on the viewport visibility, which can be enabled with the following setting: settings.lazyRender.enabled = true. This brings additional benefits as the lazy loading render speeds up the time to interactive for your form.
Additionally, SurveyJS provides the onAfterRenderQuestion event, which fires after each individual question is rendered (documentation link). This event can be leveraged to lazy load images only when the respective file question is actually rendered. By using this event, you can assign the image value to the file question dynamically with the expression options.question.value = imageObj; //imageObj has the structure you have described {type: "...", content: "..."}.
To demonstrate this approach, I’ve created a solution that you can explore.
Plnkr Demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/RmubK3OLNEsS9FcJ
Main code is here
Survey.settings.lazyRender.enabled = true;

function updateFileTemplate(_, options){
    if (!options.question || options.question.getType() != "file") return; // we only care for file questions

    const imageQuestion = options.question; // get the image question
    getRandomProfileImage()
        .then(profileImage => {
            imageQuestion.value = profileImage; // set the value
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(`Error during loading ${imageQuestion.name}. Error is: ${error}`)
        });
}

const survey = new Survey.Model(surveyJSON);
survey.onAfterRenderQuestion.add(updateFileTemplate); // attach the updateFileTemplate function as a `onAfterRenderQuestion` event handler


Notes

For some reason, I thought you were using JQuery and this is why I chose it. I just checked your code and you are using React, but the approach is the same and it would work. Sorry for that.
Dummy Image API - in this example, I’ve intentionally implemented a slow on-demand image loading process via a Dummy API, so you can observe how images are loaded one at a time (check console for that). In a production environment, you can optimize this further by preloading images and populating each file question's value independently of the user interactions or at least avoid doing the expensive fetch API call on the onAfterRenderQuestion event. I do it to demonstrate that the approach is viable
Worker.js - please don't focus on the fact that I have used web worker for this as it's an overkill or at least, not relevant. I only did at as I wanted to solve CORS issues I was having with https://randomuser.me/ random image generator. I have switched to another random image API, but the approach stayed as at least it's not blocking the UI thread and was lazy too so I kept it :)

Things to consider

Another approach worth considering is the storeDataAsText property (
https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/api-reference/file-model#storeDataAsText). As per SurveyJS docs "If you disable this property, implement SurveyModel's onUploadFiles event handler to specify how to store file content.". Essentially, leveraging this, you can implement your own storage logic for the file contents and just store the image as an Url solving a lot of the concerns you had by design. The benefit is that you will also decrease the size of the JSON making submissions faster, not to mention you can lazy load images using more standard approaches like Intersection Observer API. This depends more on the backend you have and is more work, but I think it's great option to keep in mind.

Hope this helps!
